# Did George Bernard Shaw convert on his death bed?

Tags: religion, mortality, quotes

I've seen this quote floating around all over the place. It's often used in popular Christian-lite reading (see the first page of the [Google Books search for the quote](https://www.google.com/search?q=+%E2%80%9CThe+science+to+which+I+pinned+my+faith+is+bankrupt.+It%E2%80%99s+counsels+which+should+have+established+the+millennium%2C+led%2C+instead%2C+directly+to+the+suicide+of+Europe.+I+believed+them+once.+In+their+name+I+helped+to+destroy+the+faith+of+millions+of+worshippers+&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=The+science+to+which+I+pinned+my+faith+is+bankrupt.+It%E2%80%99s+counsels+which+should+have+established+the+millennium%22&pbx=1&oq=The+science+to+which+I+pinned+my+faith+is+bankrupt.+It%E2%80%99s+counsels+which+should+have+established+the+millennium%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=4450l4450l2l5975l1l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c509dc845c0f9012&biw=1280&bih=939)), but is it true? I have never seen a worthwhile publication linked as a source, nor a date and I don't believe it's in keeping with Mr Shaw's personality or beliefs.

> The science to which I pinned my faith is bankrupt. It’s (sic) counsels which should have established the millennium, led, instead, directly to the suicide of Europe. I believed them once. In their name I helped to destroy the faith of millions of worshippers in the temples of a thousand creeds. And now they look at me and witness the great tragedy of an atheist who has lost his faith.
>
> -- Supposedly George Bernard Shaw on his deathbed

Did George Bernard Shaw really convert on his deathbed, or is this quote mis-attributed? Or does it come from somewhere else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is false.  That quote was derived from a line of dialogue by a character in his 1932 play "Too True to be Good."  The full text of which can be found [here](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0300591h.html).  If you search "bankrupt" it is the only result that comes up and you can instantly see the striking similarity between the quotes.

> THE ELDER [rising impulsively] Determinism is gone, shattered, buried with a thousand dead religions, evaporated with the clouds of a million forgotten winters. The science I pinned my faith to is bankrupt: its tales were more foolish than all the miracles of the priests, its cruelties more horrible than all the atrocities of the Inquisition. Its spread of enlightenment has been a spread of cancer: its counsels that were to have established the millennium have led straight to European suicide. And I--I who believed in it as no religious fanatic has ever believed in his superstition! For its sake I helped to destroy the faith of millions of worshippers in the temples of a thousand creeds. And now look at me and behold the supreme tragedy of the atheist who has lost his faith--his faith in atheism, for which more martyrs have perished than for all the creeds put together. Here I stand, dumb before my scoundrel of a son; for that is what you are, boy, a common scoundrel and nothing else.

There is no evidence that Shaw summarized this line of dialogue at any time near his death and contrary to [some claims](http://creationoutreach.com/id44.html) this was written more than 18 years and no less than 8 major works before his death.